# Do I need a pin_ptr to pass a literal string?

Tags: string, c++-cli, literals, pin-ptr

From a managed c++ function I want to invoke an unmanaged function that expects a 'const char *' as an argument.

Are a) and b) below correct? For b), do I need to pin_ptr 'hello'? What about a)? Thanks.

a)
`myFunction( "hello" );`

b)

```
char hello[10] ;
strcpy( hello, "hello" );
myFunction( hello );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are fine. You don't need an extra `strcpy` in b) though, just do:

```
char hello[] = "hello";
myFunction( hello );
```

which now becomes pretty much the same as a).

Comment: Thanks. And why there's no need to pin them? Because they are on the stack?

Comment: Because they are not dynamically allocated. a) is probably in read-only part of the data segment, b) is on the stack.